# How do you tell the C# compiler that a symbol is a type and not a variable when they share the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xsd

When you have a local variable named the same as a type, is there any way to tell the compiler that the symbol you have given is a type or a variable?  For instance consider (and ignore all type return errors):

```
public class sometype { public static sometype DoSomething() {} }

public string sometype { get { return sometype.DoSomething(); } } //A
public string sometype { get { return sometype.Trim(); } } //B
public sometype sometype { get { return sometype.DoSomething(); } } //C
public sometype sometype { get { return sometype.Trim(); } } //D
```

- A -> Error (no method DoSomething())
- B -> Works
- C -> Works
- D -> error (no method Trim())

#### From a more applicative point of view

(you may want to skip this if XSD bores you):

I am currently trying to get LINQ to XSD working.
In my XSD file there are xs:elements like this:

```
<xs:element name="car" type="car">
```

Where the 'car' type is defined as a simpleType like this 
(probably some more restrictions but this is it in essence):

```
<xs:simpleType name="car">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

So naturally LINQ to XSD generates code that looks like this:

```
public string car {
    get {
        XElement x = this.GetElement(XName.Get("car", ""));
        return XTypedServices.ParseValue<string>(x, XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).Datatype);
    }
    set {
        this.SetElementWithValidation(XName.Get("car", ""), value, "car", car.TypeDefinition);
    }
}
```

But this won't compile due to the aforementioned problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should fully qualify the namespace of the type.

If the type does not have a namespace, then you can prefix it with `global::` (in C# anyway).

Comment: Genius, I must be too tired to be coding right now if that didn't enter my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the global:: suggestion too.

Comment: You're welcome.  You'll see that some generated code tends to use the global prefix with a fully qualified namespace to avoid these kinds of collisions.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into C# Specification to get more information on this behavior. Here is the start of the chapter that describes it:

> 7.3 Member lookup
>   A member lookup is the process whereby the meaning of a
>   name in the context of a type is
>   determined. A  member lookup can occur
>   as part of evaluating a simple-name
>   (§7.5.2) or a member-access (§7.5.4)
>   in an  expression. If the simple-name
>   or member-access occurs as the
>   simple-expression of an
>   invocation-expression  (§7.5.5.1), the
>   member is said to be invoked.  If a
>   member is a method or event, or if it
>   is a constant, field or property of a
>   delegate type (§15), then the  member
>   is said to be invocable.  Member
>   lookup considers not only the name of
>   a member but also the number of type
>   parameters the member  has and whether
>   the member is accessible. For the
>   purposes of member lookup, generic
>   methods and nested  generic types have
>   the number of type parameters
>   indicated in their respective
>   declarations and all other  members
>   have zero type parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I never really thought about the spec before but recent work has tended to push me to the limits of the language (yeah this stupid question betrays that :P) and the spec will probably come in handy.